# Hello, I want to receive the data. The data is as follows:

Tags: php, html, dom, html-parsing

I want to receive the data.
The data is as follows:

```
<wec>0 - 0</wec><t2><t>Spor</t></t2><wec>0 - 0</wec>
```

There are two tags called wec. I want to get the values of these, but when I want to get them, the value of both of them is displayed, but I just want to get the amount of the first wec, not the second!
How does this work?
This is my code :

```
include 'simple_html_dom.php';
$get = file_get_html("https://www.example.com");
$list = $get->find('div[class="wecend"]',0);
$list_array = $list->find('wec');

for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($list_array); $i++ ){
    
     echo end($list_array);
}
```

I tried this too but it didn't work:

```
for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($list_array); $i++ ){
    
     echo end($list_array[1]);
}
```

Thank you very much for your guidance.

Comment: Why do you iterate over all tags that were found when you only want a specific one, the first?

Comment: Please guide me I'm a novice What do I need to change to get only one specific tag

Comment: You're not getting both. You're getting the last one twice. If you just want one specific, don't loop through them. If you just want want the first, remove the `foreach` and just do `echo $list_array[0];`. The function `end()` is for getting the _last_ . Btw, this question is surprisingly similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70803107/receive-information-from-a-site-and-send-it-to-the-database, where I suggested `end()` for getting the last match. Do you have multiple accounts?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use [simple_html_dom](https://github.com/voku/simple_html_dom) that you can install with [composer](https://getcomposer.org)

```
use voku\helper\HtmlDomParser;

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

$html = file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/page.html');//the param could be an url as well

$dom = HtmlDomParser::str_get_html($html);

$element = $dom->findOne('wec');

$data = $element->text();

print_r($data);//0 - 0
```

Comment: `include 'simple_html_dom.php';` is the first line of his code!